# Disclosure of recipient’s forward email address when my email bounces

Tags: email, email-bounces, mail-forwarding, privacy

A few times I had a situation like this:

1. I sent an email to foobar@example.com.
2. For this email, I received a delivery failure report, giving reasons like "550 5.1.1" (user unknown) or "552-5.7.0" (security issue).
3. In this delivery failure report, a different email address is mentioned

   > Mail delivery to the following recipient has finally failed:
   >
   > john.doe@example.edu

   or

   > Final-Recipient: rfc822; john.doe@example.edu
   >   Original-Recipient: rfc822;john.doe@example.edu

So, I assume that the owner of `foobar@example.com` decided to forward emails to `john.doe@example.edu`. But I only learned about this email address thanks to an error. This could be a privacy problem for the recipient.

Is it standards-compliant to disclose the forward email address in this context? If yes, is there a way to prevent such a disclosure?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to prevent disclose the forward email address?

**Linux/Unix:**
Instead of direct forwarding in `~/.forward` (or via `aliases`) forward using e.g. `procmail`.

`~/.forward` does not change envelope sender.
`procmail` by default changes it to account doing forward.  [`man procmailex`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/procmailex) provides an example how to avoid forwarding loops by setting and checking `X-Loop:` header.